# Which is more common, “decide to do” or “decide on doing”?

Tags: expressions

Today I did my homework and found one question that is too difficult to answer to me.

The question was like this:
She decided to marry Tom.
≒She decided ( ) marrying Tom.

I’ve been studying English for 6 years. But I think I’ve almost never heard the expression “decide on doing”.(At least I don’t remember that.)
Is this expression relatively common, or is this so usual?

If the two expressions “decide to do/decide on doing” are used in different ways, please tell me the difference.

Comment: The best way to decide questions like these is to use Google Books Ngram Viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decide+to+do%2Cdecide+on+doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecide%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecide%20on%20doing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: or [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decide_INF+to+do%2Cdecide_INF+on+doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cdecide_INF%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdecided%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdecide%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdecides%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeciding%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cdecide_INF%20on%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdecided%20on%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdecide%20on%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdecides%20on%20doing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeciding%20on%20doing%3B%2Cc0) (takes infection into account)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's an answer here actually: [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/difference-between-decided-on-and-decided-to/78172#:~:text=plan%20of%20action.-,I%20have%20decided%20to%20emigrate%20to%20Australia.,I%20have%20decided%20on%20emigration](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/difference-between-decided-on-and-decided-to/78172#:%7E:text=plan%20of%20action.-,I%20have%20decided%20to%20emigrate%20to%20Australia.,I%20have%20decided%20on%20emigration).

In short, it said this:

> I have decided on + object
>
> I have decided to + verb
>
> The usage is based on the construction of the sentence.
>
> Decide **to** suggests that you have chosen a plan of action.
>
> Decide **on** suggests that you have chosen one from two or more options that you were weighing.

In some cases, I have personally seen some using "on" in your situation ('decide (on) marrying Tom'); so I guess it depends on the situation. Hope this helps.